# JavaFX : Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using JavaFX and when I run with java application I have this error. The jar file of javaFX is included in libraries of the project but but I don't know what this exception means.I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

I do the following :

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

and the output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:107)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$203(GtkApplication.java:151)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:140)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
... 9 more
```

Comment: The error is saying some class is missing a no-argument constructor. Is this your exact code?

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: @Slaw yes, this is. I'm using Java 1.8.0_212

Comment: @Slaw I'm new in Java FX and this code is generated automatically when I create a JavaFX project.